# Strange behavior in python when comparing lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iterator

I am working on a project that deals with parsing emails and saving them to a database. Parsing the emails and saving the parsed emails to a logfile works without problems, but the moment I try to read from the logfile I encounter a strange problem. Here is the code:

```
def main():
global email_batch, temp_email_batch

read_logfile = True
while read_logfile:
    try:
        with open('a-1-test.json', 'r') as outfile:
            temp_email_batch = json.load(outfile)
            outfile.close()
    except IOError as err:
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(err.errno, err.strerror)
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

    if temp_email_batch != email_batch:
        email_batch = temp_email_batch
        print "not equal log files"
        # saveData()
        for parsedMail in email_batch:
            collection.insert(parsedMail)
    else:
        print "equal log files"
        time.sleep(10)
```

I can read the log file (here its just a test file in json format) and save the data. The check:

```
if temp_email_batch != email_batch:
```

Has a strange behavior when I try to compare the two batches. The idea is to check if I have already gotten the data from the logfile or if new data has been written to the logfile. If i comment out the iteration:

```
for parsedMail in email_batch:
            # http_client.addRawData(sourceName, parsedMail)
            collection.insert(parsedMail)
```

The check works fine and sees when no new data has been added to the logfile, but if I uncomment it, it seems as the check always gives true even if the temp_email_batch IS EQUAL to email_batch so it keeps saving the same emails to the collection.

I am quite flabbergasted. Does the iterator change in some way the list? All my programming instincts say it doesn't, but there is certainly something wrong there if by just commenting it the code works without problems and jumps to the else clause if the temp is equal to the previous batch.

Thank you in advance,
Georgi

EDIT:

So I found a work-around by not passing directly through the pymongo library to save my data to the DB but using json remote process call and set up a script that defines couple of methods for database manipulation. By using the RPC I have no problems and the code works fine.

Comment: I would say python is checking if `temp_email_batch` and `email_batch` are different entities rather than whether their content is different. You will probably need to implement this comparison in order to make it work.

Comment: Can you try using something like `if all(email in email_batch for email in temp_email_batch):`

Comment: @cnluzon, I'm afraid that's incorrect. It is the `is` operator that does identity tests in Python. This is still just an equality test.

Comment: By the way, should't it be `for parsedMail in temp_email_batch` or am I understanding your problem wrong?

Comment: @cnluzon It could be but then it would behave the same when I comment out or don't comment out the iterator. If the temp is different than the batch, then I just copy the temp to the batch. Thats why m iterating over email_batch and not the temp

Comment: Honestly, I'll bet this is because you're using Mongo and it's adding an `_id` field to each dict after you save it. That would make the resulting list of mutated dicts fail the equality test.

Comment: I thought that would be the case @jwilner but I got confused by the fact that the contents of both lists are supposed to be the same. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Jkdc I tried but when I use this code the check is always True, even if the dictionaries are different.

Comment: @jwilner But the _id from Mongo has nothing to do with this I think. It is not like I get the dictionaries from Mongo, the check is done before I add them to the collection, so there is no key "_id"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with how dict or list equality is implemented in Python.

List equality in Python is predicated on size, order, and the equality of the contained values. That means, after establishing two lists are the same size, the interpreter will basically zip the two lists and call == on each pair in turn.

Dict equality is similar, only they're unordered, so order doesn't factor in. It can be conceptually thought of as creating a set of key-value pairs from each dict and asking if the sets are unequal.

What I'm getting to here, is the two lists of dicts must really be unequal, and I'm 95% sure this is because you're forgetting that dicts are mutable and that PyMongo, when you insert or save a dict to a collection adds the an _id field in place to the dict. Remember, the dict is mutable -- all references to that dict in the runtime now also have the _id field.

However, the JSON file is of course outside the runtime. When you load the dicts again, they don't have the field. To you, and for most intents and purposes, the two lists of dicts may seem the same, but they are now unequal because of the _id field in each of the dicts of the old list.

If you want to keep at this route, you will need to work in avoiding the _id field in your comparison (hacky) . Or, you could set up a unique key to the collection and handle the duplicate key errors that will be raised (the best option, probably, if you're actually concerned about duplicates). Or, you could copy each dict before writing it to the DB, and write the copy, not the original, so that old references don't get the new field (also hacky). Really, this requires you to think more carefully about how you define the equality of your data structures.

Welcome to mutable state. It sucks.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I tried copying the content of email_batch to a second temporary list and using that list to add to the Mongo database, but encounter the same problem. What I can do is check the items one by one in the list and compare their message Id which is unique. But I am not sure what is the best way to do that in python (in other words the most efficient)

Comment: @GeorgiNikolov, it is not enough to copy the containing list. You must copy every single contained dict. Again, I don't recommend this route -- it is a bad coding pattern -- but to make my point: import the copy module, and change the insertion line to `collection. insert(copy.deepcopy(parsedMail))`. Again, to make this really work please consider establishing a unique index on your collection and handling duplicate key errors.

Comment: Each dict contains a key:value pair Message-Id which is unique per email. I can use that as a unique identifier. How would be the best way to check email per email in both lists if the Message-Ids correspond?

Comment: Try: `lists_are_equal = len(list_1) == len(list_2) and all(a["message-id"] == b["message-id“] for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))`. Again, I think the better solution is to create a unique index in Mongo on the message id and to catch and log the duplicate key errors, but otherwise ignore them. This will actually simplify your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "create a unique index in Mongo on the message id and to catch and log the duplicate key errors". Can you give an example?